# Bulk insert on MongoDB using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, multer

I'm trying to parse a CSV file obtained via POST to JSON and then upload it to my MongoDB database.
The problem is that I've found the next script is not so performing: it's not so fast and it's using up to 1.3GB of memory when I'm trying to parse 4 CSV of 8.5MB each (~85'000 lines).

Has someone some suggestions to improve it?

```
router.route('/upload').post(upload.single('data'), function (req, res) {
    fs.rename(UPLOAD_PATH+req.file.filename, UPLOAD_PATH+req.file.originalname, function(err){
    if (err) return res.status(500).send("Problem in POST\n");
    res.status(200).send("File registered\n");

    var arr = []; // TODO should fix: too much memory?

    csv().fromFile(UPLOAD_PATH+req.file.originalname)
        .on('json', (jsonObj)=>{
            arr.push(jsonObj);
        })
        .on('done', (error)=>{
            console.log('End of parsing, length: '+arr.length)
            Ping.insertMany(arr)
                .then(function(docs) {
                    console.log('Inserted everything on DB')
                    arr.length = 0;
                })
                .catch(function(err) {
                    // TODO
                });
        });
    });
});
```

**EDIT1: resolved using mongoimport**

```
router.route('/upload').post(upload.single('data'), function (req, res) {
fs.rename(UPLOAD_PATH+req.file.filename, UPLOAD_PATH+req.file.originalname, function(err){
    if (err) return res.status(500).send("Problem in POST\n");
    res.status(200).send("File registered\n");

    const { exec } = require('child_process'); // TODO secrets?
    exec('mongoimport -h host -d db -c pings -u user -p passwd --file '+UPLOAD_PATH+req.file.originalname+' --type csv --headerline', (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (err) {
            // TODO
            console.log('Error')
            return;
        }

    });
});
});
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Isn't there a `mongoimport` tool better suited for this sort of thing? Is this something that has to be programmatically solved? If so, the end of https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/bulk-import-a-csv-file-into-mongodb-using-mongoose-with-nodejs--cms-29574 discusses some techniques.

Comment: @jdv Tried it, the final part too; didn't resolved :(

Comment: It is unclear if `mongoimport` worked or not, because you use the word "resolved". I'm not sure wrapping `mongoimport` in an exec is really how you want to do this. You've just added a whole raft of complications to something you could try and figure out from a command line. Do you need a programmatic solution? Is this a one-time thing or something you expect to do over and over?